# export 'default' (imported as 'VueFire') was not found in 'vuefire'

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, vuefire

Every single tutorial for how to use Firebase with Vue says that in the main.js file I have to add Vue.use(VueFire); which makes sense. But then I just get this message export 'default' (imported as 'VueFire') was not found in 'vuefire'.

I tried using import * as VueFire from 'vuefire' and it didn't give the error message anymore, but it doesn't seem to be using the plugin.

this is the main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import VueFire from 'vuefire'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueFire);

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Older documentation I think. Try this instead.

```
import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire'
Vue.use(firestorePlugin)
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue thank you so much =) I looked at the vuefire git repo and the export is {rtdbPlugin} for the realtime database which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

just looking at new documentation here 
https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/getting-started.html

```
 import Vue from 'vue' import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire'

 Vue.use(firestorePlugin)
```